# How terminate a method when an event fired

Tags: c#, .net, events

I have a Validation method and a validation counter, I fire an event when the count of errors is equal to a number. How do I terminate the validation process? Maybe I should use Observer pattern?

```
class ValidationClass
{
private int errorsCount;
private delegate void CompleteHandler();
private event CompleteHandler ValidationComplete;

public int ErrorsCount
{
     set
       {
         errorsCount = value;
         if (errorsCount == 20)
         {
          ValidationComplete();
         }
        }
       get { return errorsCount; }
}

public void ValidationClass()//constructor
{
 ValidationComplete += ExcelHelpers_Complete;
}

void Validation_Complete() // 
{
//terminate Validate() and return false; how?
}


public bool Validate()
{
                   for(...){
                       ErrorsCount++;

                        for(...){

                         ....
                         ErrorsCount++;


                  }
             ....
             //others conditions that increment ErrorsCount
         }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your subscriber check the number of error count and do nothing if its past your maximum range. If your subscriber does not have access to the publisher object than pass the count inside the event itself. Your subscriber could also unsubscribe once this condition has been met.

Comment: tnx Lockdowne,  was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Move the following code into your `Validate()` method:

```
if (errorsCount == 20)
{
    ValidationComplete();
}
```

Now use `break` statement to abort your loop when the condition is true and raise `ValidationComplete()` event thereafter.

Your property will look like this:

```
public int ErrorsCount
{
    set { errorsCount = value; }
    get { return errorsCount; }
}
```

and `Validate()` method would look like this:

```
public bool Validate()
{
    for(...){
        ErrorsCount++;
        if(Check20()) break;

        for(...){
            ....
            ErrorsCount++;
            if(Check20()) break; 
        }

        if(Check20()) break;

        ....
        //others conditions that increment ErrorsCount
        if(Check20()) break;
    }
}

private bool Check20()
{
    if(ErrorsCount==20)
    {
        ValidationComplete();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you dislike all that repetition, you can create a small function for it too.

Comment: Ok but in this way i force to check every time increment the errorCount. could you give me cleaner code

Comment: @Mohammadreza: You are going to do that every time one way or the other. Putting the code inside the property doesn't mean it won't be run every time.

Comment: Tnx but i want utilize DRY principle (don't repeating if condition for every increment.

Comment: @Mohammadreza: As I said, you can just make a function for it. And as I said, you have to check the if condition one way or another.

Comment: @Mohammadreza: Created a function for you. Note that you still have to check it every time you increment `ErrorCount`.

Answer (score 0):

Throw a custom exception inside the ErrorsCount setter (or better yet, create an IncrementErrorCount() method) when ErrorCount reaches 20.  Then catch it and return.

```
try {
    ...
    IncrementErrorCount();
    ...
} catch(TooManyErrorsException) {
   return;
}
```

It is a bit of an anti-pattern of using exceptions for control throw,  but if this is an exceptional circumstance, and if this is a client app and this doesn't happen in a loop, it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: it's hard to tell from your abbreviated code, but if all your checks are in loops, you may also be able to put the check into the for loop condition:

```
for(...; oldCondition && ErrorCount < 20; ...) {

}
ValidationComplete();
```